# IOS uitableviewcell changing content of cell while scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview

HI I am developing small IOS application in which I am using table view with custom cell.My cell contains simple view inside that I have one text and one image.So for some cells image is there and for some cell its not there. So I am adding and removing it dynamically. It is showing right output but once I scroll and again come back to same cell it remove that image.I tried it in following way

```
MediaContentCell *cell = (MediaContentCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = (MediaContentCell *)[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

[self setVideoCell:cell withIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

-(void) setVideoCell:(MediaContentCell *)cell withIndex:(int)index
{
if(videoData.trailer)
{
    cell.playButton.hidden = NO;
}
else
{
  //        [cell.playButton removeFromSuperview];

    cell.playButton.hidden = YES;

    // adding new contraints ....
        [cell.contentDescription addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell.mediaTitle attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell.contentDescription attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:-10]];

        [cell.contentDescription addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell.mediaSubtitle attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell.contentDescription attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:-10]];
}
}
```

In above case it is showing correct output. But once I scroll up and down it is changing output. How to solve solve this problem. I want correct cells with image and others will not image. Need Some help. Thank you.

Comment: Where does videoData come from?

Comment: Video data is my data object. it contains my data nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting ALL of your `cell.playButton`s to `hidden` if `videoData.trailer` returns false. You're not using `index` in your `setVideoCell:withIndex:` either.

You're also adding constraints EVERY TIME a cell is displayed, which results in a lot of duplicated constraints. The constraints have to be set once, inside `MediaContentCell`'s `init` or `awakeFromNib` methods.

Comment: thank you for quick replay. I will try your solution and let you know. I have set constraints inside my storyboard. But once I hide button then I want to use that space for my text with some constraints. Thats why I am adding those only when I am hiding my image.

Comment: You're not removing them anywhere though! You're just adding new ones everytime.

Comment: Ok I suggest you create two cells, one for each state, with a different reuse identifier and appropriate constraints (inside the storeyboard!) and then use the appropriate reuse identifier based on `if(videoData.trailer)` on your first line.

Answer (score 1):

Do you happen to be calling your above code asynchronously? I was having your same issue, and I fixed it by taking it out of a `dispatch_async` call (it didn't need to be asynchronous).